# How to stringify an arithmetic result in a preprocessor macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

How should I write a macro that receive two arguments and  (giving for example `3` and `2`) return the following output?

```
The sum of 3 and 2 is 5
```

That is what I write, but it doesn't compile:

```
#define SOMMA(x, y) puts("La somma di " #x " e " #y " e' " #(x+y));
```

calling it with

```
SOMMA (a, b);
```

with `a` and `b` introduced before...

Comment: I think you're looking for the preprocessor '#' operation. See, eg, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html (Not up to rewriting that as a complete Answer right now, and their descriptions a good one anyway. BTW, google found this quite easily, though it helps to know what you're looking for.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `printf` instead of `puts` and do something like that.

```
#define SOMMA(x, y) printf("sum of %d and %d is %d\n", x, y, (x + y));
```

Note `%d` only accepts integer values so you probably need another macro for double/floats.

**EDIT**

As rcgdlr pointed out you could also use `sprintf` or `snprintf` if you want to create a string containing your result.

```
#define MAXLEN 256
#define SOMMA(x, y, res) snprintf(res, MAXLEN, "sum of %d and %d is %d\n", x, y, (x + y));
```

Use it like that:

```
char buffer[MAXLEN];
SOMMA(4, 6, buffer);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: or use sprintf if the goal is to produce a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SOMMA(x, y) printf("The Sum Of A = %d and B= %d is %d",a,b,(a+b))
```